What are "Funding Events" for Equity Swaps
have been using PE Swaps deck on Swaps pricing as a reference to understand Equity Swaps better. https://osf.io/72693/download. As I understand it, the Funding Leg Present value can be determined as:

Where t is the valuation Date, N is the notional principal amount, i is the ith cash flow, tau_i is the accrual period of the ith cashflow, D_i is the discount factor, F_i is the simply compounded forward rate, and S is the floating spread. Few Qs on this:

What are "Notional principal amount", "cash flow" , "accrual period of cashflow", "forward rate" and "simple spread"  mean here? again is basic Qs, any resource to find explanation would be very appreciated.
In the context of calculating this PV, do there exist actual "exec Funding events" which would be calced? are they each dividend payment event?


Q1. For simplicity consider a loan from a Bank. The notional amount is the amount you borrowed. Cash flows are the interest payments you make. Accrual period is the time between payments in years (for example if u are required to pay interest quarterly the $\tau$ is 0.25), forward rate is the rate you are required to pay for example the SOFR rate expressed on a per year basis (for ex 5% a year) for the relevant period eg the 3d quarter of 2027), simple spread is an amount tacked on to the published forward rate because the bank has decide you must pay more than SOFR).

Ex: you borrowed 10,000 USD at annual 5% plus simple spread of 1% payable quarterly, then your  interest payment will be 10000*(0.05+0.01)*0.25 = 150 USD. A funding event example is you decide you need an additional 5000 and the Bank approves. Then the notional goes up to 15,000.
